# Session.save(obj) return zero

Tags: hibernate

I am new to hibernate.I am creating a table using hibernate. I can see the result in db. but my session.save(obj) still return zero although it should return one i guess. This is my code:

```
public static int register(User u) { 
    int i = 0;  
    Session session = new AnnotationConfiguration().configure().buildSessionFactory().openSession();
    try {

        Transaction t = session.beginTransaction();
        // t.begin();  

        i = (Integer) session.save(u);  
        System.out.println("Value of i is::"+(Integer)session.save(u));
        System.out.println(session.save(u).getClass().getName());
        t.commit();  
        session.close();
    }
    catch(RuntimeException e) {
        session.getTransaction().rollback();
        throw e;
    }

   return i;  
}
```

I am using jsp and creating a  form and then passing the data. Can someone help me with this?

Comment: *although it should return one i guess*: what's the basis for your guess? What in the documentation of Hibernate and in the code of your entity (which you didn't post makes you think it should return 1? Also, does the documentation recommend creating a brand new session factory every time you need a session?

Comment: can u post your User Model here.What type of generator u r using to auto generate primary key. or try this Integer id  =  (Integer) session.save(u);

Answer (score 0):

try this one
Integer id = (Integer) session.save(u);